# Trying to get CSV line as 2 dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

So I'm trying to read a CSV which has a couple of lines and will be compared with a User-Input. This input is an array of id's the user chooses ($talente). The array with the id's will be splitted, the script opens the CSV and reads the line equal to the id's. It works nice but reads the CSV line by line into another one-dimensional array. But I need the lines to be an array already, so that I get a two-dimensional array at the end.

My script so far looks like this:

```
<?php

$talente = $_GET['talente'];

$talentline = array();

$i = 0;
$myFile = fopen("talente.csv", "r");

foreach ($talente as $talent) {
    if ($talent == $i+1) {          
        while (($data = fgetcsv($myFile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $num = count($data);

                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $talentline[][] = $data[$c];
                }

        //$talentline[] = $lines[$i];

        }
        fclose($myFile);
    }
    $i++;

}

print_r(array_values($talentline));

/*echo $talentline[1];
echo $talentline[2];
*/
?>
```

The outcome so far is every line with every element, but in a one-dimensional array instead of a two-dimensional:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Schild ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Licht ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1w10 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => - ) [5] => Array ( [0] => Schutz ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => Licht ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 1w10 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => - ) [10] => Array ( [0] => Licht ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => Licht ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 1w10 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => - ) [15] => Array ( [0] => Genesung ) [16] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [17] => Array ( [0] => Licht ) [18] => Array ( [0] => - ) [19] => Array ( [0] => - ) [20] => Array ( [0] => Aufopfern ) [21] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [22] => Array ( [0] => Licht ) [23] => Array ( [0] => - ) [24] => Array ( [0] => - ) )
```

Comment: Try`fgetcsv()`?  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: The first thing I tried but it somehow just placed the elements of the line into one array instead of making a two-dimensional array.

Comment: It would have been better to provide the code you actually __did__ try with `fgetcsv` that didn't work. This code makes no sense at all since it's just reading the csv file into an array with every single iteration of `$_GET['talente']`. There's no actual comparison of any kind being done here. So it's difficult to tell what the desired behavior should be.

Comment: Edited. This is the best I came so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? Read the CSV once for speed, then use [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to filter the CSV down to the desired rows.

```
<?php

$talente = $_GET['talente'];

$myFile = fopen("talente.csv", "r");
$csv = [];
while ($data = fgetcsv($myFile, 1000, ",")) {
    $csv[] = $data;
}
fclose($myFile);

$talentLine = array_filter($csv, function($key) use ($talente) {
    return in_array($key, $talente);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r(array_values($talentline));
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!